# Swift: self in initializer has type (T) -> () -> T

Tags: swift, types, initialization

**TL;DR**:

How does an `NSObject`'s `self` variable acquire the type `(T) -> () -> T`?

**Remarks**

I can see *why* the use of `self` this way is not legal. But I am trying to make sense of the second error message.

**The Code**

```
struct DummyStorer {
    let dummy: Dummy
}

struct Dummy {
    let storer = DummyStorer(dummy: self)
    // Use of unresolved identifier 'self'
    // OK, that's reasonable. But...
}

class Dummy : NSObject {
    let storer = DummyStorer(dummy: self)
    // Cannot convert value of type '(Dummy) -> () -> Dummy' to expected argument type 'Dummy'
    // ... how does the compiler arrive at this?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is part of `NSObjectProtocol`

```
public protocol NSObjectProtocol {


    func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool

    var hash: Int { get }


    var superclass: AnyClass? { get }


    func `self`() -> Self         // << here !!
```